# When update values it update all tables

Tags: php

I just want it I am writing table on to update itself.
https://i.gyazo.com/177818ad99fabae31c3a37c98e0306b4.gif

```
<?php
if ($_POST['response']) {
    mysql_connect ("localhost", "root", "*") or die ('Error: ' . mysql_error());
    mysql_select_db("habix") or die ('Data error:' . mysql_error());
    $text = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['comments']); 
    $query="UPDATE user_tickets_table SET response='$text'";
    mysql_query($query) or die ('Error updating database' . mysql_error());
}
?>

<td><textarea name='comments' placeholder='Skriv en kommentar tilbake!' style='border:1px'>".$row['response']."</textarea><input type='submit' value='Svar!' name='response' '/></td></form>";
```

http://pastebin.com/SaRiVxcU

Comment: add where to your underlying update query.

Comment: (update query)...Which you should add to your question!

Comment: http://pastebin.com/SaRiVxcU

Comment: No. Add it to your question in a block code.

Comment: looks like it was any fault with the php code not came up. has taken it into pastebin file

Comment: Just needed proper formatting ;-) Four spaces in front, or highlight it all and click `{}`

Comment: You just need a `WHERE` clause in your update. `UPDATE user_tickets_table SET response='$text' WHERE ...`

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/update.html

Answer (score 2):

If you want update only a single row you mus add a where clause for filter the row involved eg: using an id for row  Assuming your col for row id is your_id_col and your related  value is numeric and in $your_row_id var

```
UPDATE user_tickets_table 
SET response='$text'
where your_id_col =  $your_row_id
```

Comment: Error updating databaseYou have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1